# Javascript console message: createUserWithEmailAndPassword failed: First argument "email" must be a valid string

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying  to create a user using javascript. When i click insert it always show that the email needs to be a valid string.

So this is my input fields

```
 <div class="inputContainer">
                <input class="input" id="fname" type="text" placeholder="a"> <label class="label"  for="room_name"><b>First Name </b></label> 
              </div>
              <div class="inputContainer">
                <input class="input" id="mname" type="text" placeholder="a"> <label class="label"  for="room_name"><b>Middle Name </b></label> 
              </div>
              <div class="inputContainer">
                <input class="input" id="lname" type="text" placeholder="a"> <label class="label"  for="room_name"><b>Last Name </b></label> 
              </div>
              <div class="inputContainer">
                <input class="input"  id="contact" type="text" placeholder="a"><label class="label"  for="room_name"><b>Contact Number </b></label> 
              </div>
    
              
            
    
                <div class="inputContainer">
                  <input class="input"  id="dept" type="text" placeholder="a"><label class="label"  for="room_name"><b>Department</b></label> 
                </div>
    
                <div class="inputContainer">
                  <input class="input"  id="email" type="text" placeholder="a"><label class="label"  for="room_name"><b>Email</b></label> 
                </div>
    
                <div class="inputContainer">
                  <input class="input"  id="password" type="text" placeholder="a"><label class="label"  for="room_name"><b>Password</b></label> 
                </div>
    
                <button id="Insert" class="editrooms-save" >Insert</button>
              </div>
            </div>
```

And this is my javascript. I already add the firebase config there.

```
document.getElementById("Insert").addEventListener("click", register);  

function register(){

fname = document.getElementById('fname');
mname = document.getElementById('mname');
lname = document.getElementById('lname');
contact = document.getElementById('contact');
dept = document.getElementById('dept');
email = document.getElementById('email');
password = document.getElementById('password');
 


firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
 .then(function(){
     var user = auth.currentUser
     

     var user_data = {
       fname: fname.value,
       mname: mname.value,
       lname: lname.value,
       contact: contact.value,
       dept: dept.value,
       email: email.value,
       last_login: Date.now()
     }

     firebase.database().ref().child("adminaccount/" + user.uid).set(user_data)



     alert('user Created!')
 })
 .catch(function(error){
   var error_code = error.code
   var error_message = error.message

   alert(error_message)
 })



}
```

....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: `email = document.getElementById('email');` is an html element. You need to get its `.value`

Comment: thank you but another error came up and it says "set failed: value argument contains undefined in property 'adminaccount.vJGsHaLI6JReRjVOoPcu0C2CBNH2.fname'"

Comment: I fixed it i just remove the .value inside the ```var user_data = {
       fname: fname.value,
       mname: mname.value,
       lname: lname.value,
       contact: contact.value,
       dept: dept.value,
       email: email.value,
       last_login: Date.now()
     }```

Comment: That sounds like an answer @derpirscher  --- Cielo: you may get a different error after fixing the first one, but that'd be a new question.